So much extra junk in Llama Index metadata when embedding
I am using Llama Index to embed a series of documents.  The embeddings are working fine.  I have modified the metadata and that is appearing my db, fine.  So, what's the problem you ask?  Well, Llama Index is adding a load of junk to the metadata that I cannot "pop" or otherwise remove.  I even created, entirely, my own metadata variable.  No change.  Like this example.
{"file_path": "path/to/text.txt", "file_name": "myTextFiles.txt", "file_type": "text/plain", "file_size": 3024349, "creation_date": "2024-05-19", "last_modified_date": "2023-11-24", 

That above is all my metadata.  Then, Llama Index adds all of this below.  How do I ensure that what is below is not added to my metadata?
"_node_content": "{\"id_\": \"e0faec05-8a68-43b2-a2d1-51c307775877\", \"embedding\": null, \"metadata\": {\"file_path\": \"/path/to/textFiles.txt\", \"file_name\": \"paul_graham_essays.txt\", \"file_type\": \"text/plain\", \"file_size\": 3024349, \"creation_date\": \"2024-05-19\", \"last_modified_date\": \"2023-11-24\"}, \"excluded_embed_metadata_keys\": [\"file_name\", \"file_type\", \"file_size\", \"creation_date\", \"last_modified_date\", \"last_accessed_date\"], \"excluded_llm_metadata_keys\": [\"file_name\", \"file_type\", \"file_size\", \"creation_date\", \"last_modified_date\", \"last_accessed_date\"], \"relationships\": {\"1\": {\"node_id\": \"b51cd20a-6dbd-4d1b-b46b-4aa4f4d3d358\", \"node_type\": \"4\", \"metadata\": {\"file_path\":  \"file_name\": \"texts.txt\", \"file_type\": \"text/plain\", \"file_size\": 3024349, \"creation_date\": \"2024-05-19\", \"last_modified_date\": \"2023-11-24\"}, \"hash\": \"412d644dc9ebf3d7aab8e41560ad724ffa0bc36922ce428305ddd694c2b41b3a\", \"class_name\": \"RelatedNodeInfo\"}, \"2\": {\"node_id\": \"74b97b26-d3b4-4b84-ac0e-e401922ff5f9\", \"node_type\": \"1\", \"metadata\": {\"file_path\":  \"file_name\": \"TEXTS.txt\", \"file_type\": \"text/plain\", \"file_size\": 3024349, \"creation_date\": \"2024-05-19\", \"last_modified_date\": \"2023-11-24\"}, \"hash\": \"708868dc8c11472299c40c4ad44d643e9aea2dbe9c1bef325cc0dd0336d25d19\", \"class_name\": \"RelatedNodeInfo\"}, \"3\": {\"node_id\": \"d82535b2-421f-46ca-9972-df8d1e5a0df6\", \"node_type\": \"1\", \"metadata\": {}, \"hash\": \"e65800e1e75593d6e58717024fbcf523f02a9f7a9e7a5f9ea739c7c5780fb26f\", \"class_name\": \"RelatedNodeInfo\"}}, \"text\": \"\", \"start_char_idx\": 3767, \"end_char_idx\": 8347, \"text_template\": \"{metadata_str}\\n\\n{content}\", \"metadata_template\": \"{key}: {value}\", \"metadata_seperator\": \"\\n\", \"class_name\": \"TextNode\"}", "_node_type": "TextNode", "document_id": "b51cd20a-6dbd-4d1b-b46b-4aa4f4d3d358", "doc_id": "b51cd20a-6dbd-4d1b-b46b-4aa4f4d3d358", "ref_doc_id": "b51cd20a-6dbd-4d1b-b46b-4aa4f4d3d358"}


Instead of using SimpleDirectoryReader iterate over your files yourself and use the field excluded_embed_metadata_keys of the Document class.
E.g. like so excluded_embed_metadata_keys=["citation", "file_number", "page_number", "plain_text"].
This works for me :)
